# Getting 403 randomly on files

Tags: files, 9, authentication-authorization

I have a `react-native` app that authenticates with Drupal via oAuth2 (simple_oauth, openidconnect) and do not use cookies. I use my access token for all rest calls, `images` and other files. Very randomly and consistently, the response for the files are `html` - the login form to be precise. Not all files but some of them and randomly. Sometime it works, sometimes it doesn't. If I logout and login again, it works for a few minutes and then it's gone after awhile. I do use a private file system. I've checked the directory permissions and they are all `755`. I don't know what it is or how to resolve it.

Simple oauth settings:

```
Access token expiration time: 604800
Authorization code expiration time: 604800
Refresh token expiration time: 1209600
```

Filesystem:

[image]

Downloading images on RN:

```
export const downloadImage = (_uri, _path, _extension, _access_token) => {
  const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
  const path = dirs.DocumentDir + '/' + _path + '.' + _extension;

  // send http request in a new thread (using native code)
  return RNFetchBlob.config({path: path}).fetch('GET', _uri, {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + _access_token,
  });
};
```

I enabled ForensicLog on apache2 to monitor the headers too and here is the result:

```
GET /system/files/styles/crop_1_1/private/2021-10/image-2.jpg?h=75dde18b&itok=KTg7ozUt HTTP/1.1|Host:example.co.uk|Accept:*/*|Connection:keep-alive|Cookie:SESScd3de411e6a4fa7f7d3a2b14dd1164d2=q7cGe3QFrHDFCceeaP3etssZOPxl6nhWmngykV9zKJo9wAPn|If-Modified-Since:Fri, 29 Oct 2021 16%3a39%3a29 GMT|Accept-Language:en-us|Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImUzZTZlNjNjZTI0OGEyYzYyNTUzNDRkYzg5NTk3N2NhOTZiNGI5YWQ0ZTIwYjRiNWVmODI4OTc4OWRhODI1MDQ3MjNhNzIzNmYwZmQxZmZjIn0.eyJhdWQiOiJhNDIyNTg1Ni0wM2Y1LTQzYTctODkzNS1hZDdhYTFiMjJhNmUiLCJqdGkiOiJlM2U2ZTYzY2UyNDhhMmM2MjU1MzQ0ZGM4OTU5NzdjYTk2YjRiOWFkNGUyMGI0YjVlZjgyODk3ODlkYTgyNTA0NzIzYTcyMzZmMGZkMWZmYyIsImlhdCI6MTYzNjQ2ODU1NiwibmJmIjoxNjM2NDY4NTU2LCJleHAiOjE2MzcwNzMzNTYsInN1YiI6IjE0NDM2Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbImF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZWQiXX0.rt4h-eeNyXlw5HoR6KvFnP5iujh4Wkg_evuqQcEn7lrJt0wE2b7N8nUoRgdBEa-JA4c5SD3Euok3QwIzXuzJYB3brXaztuXC_TE-BkrscA7HB5-4jQ5JYbQI6U9WkJPH2WPCDYbyrIQTF1d4lQ76A1-61xL2G7K9scaGJ-nAZskTRJjsx7PGjv8FcDR1crI6M3fE_nTwSDW5KbwVHv4Tt7549YKR7sIlIzUHZ6aU4FPwF0FDekkqv3qw-xYD4TyfnTAI9-70edkq2QjI4uwixgb9zrn7XNl9zxOX7deIdG_TQ7Rc0arfbr-1ZABQa9UW72HVeA5IKvjjBZB4VST4DQ|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br|User-Agent:MY%2520APP/41 CFNetwork/1237 Darwin/20.5.0
GET /user/login?destination=system/files/styles/crop_1_1/private/2021-10/image-2.jpg%253Fh%253D75dde18b%2526itok%253DKTg7ozUt HTTP/1.1|Host:example.co.uk|Accept:*/*|Cookie:SESScd3de411e6a4fa7f7d3a2b14dd1164d2=q7cGe3QFrHDFCceeaP3etssZOPxl6nhWmngykV9zKJo9wAPn|User-Agent:MY%2520APP/41 CFNetwork/1237 Darwin/20.5.0|Accept-Language:en-us|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br|Connection:keep-alive
```

Comment: If you're getting the login form in a response, it is likely that you have requested a resource that requires authentication without providing proper authentication.  Are you sure you are refreshing your token properly?

Comment: @PatrickKenny I'm requesting files directly. I am sure the token is fine. If it wasn't, all the API calls would return a 403. But I'm happy to test this.